# Flask Form not submitting/not calling post method

Tags: python, forms, flask

I have the following form, which when pressed doesn't submit.

```
<div class="ui form" method="post" action="{{ url_for('filter_ui_data_sources') }}">
  <div class="fields">
 {{select(argument1, argument2, ...)}}
    <div class="six wide field">
        <button type="submit" class="ui primary button" name="submit_button"><i class='search icon'></i> Filter data sources</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The select is just a macro that yields a multiselection search box. 
This is the method it should call, but never gets here.

```
@app.route("/ui/data_sources", methods=["POST"])
def filter_ui_data_sources():
    return something
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your form in actual form tags:

```
<form class="ui form" method="post" action="{{ url_for('filter_ui_data_sources') }}">
  <div class="fields">
 {{select(argument1, argument2, ...)}}
    <div class="six wide field">
        <button type="submit" class="ui primary button" name="submit_button"><i class='search icon'></i> Filter data sources</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```